# Hi, I am trying to CASE WHEN but its not working for the below. it returns back with the same statement when executed

Tags: sql, case-when

when[Actual turn around time] is above the TAT value then I want it as Over.

```
CASE(WHEN TAT = 3 AND  [Actual turn around time] > 3 THEN 'Over' 
     WHEN TAT = 7 AND  [Actual turn around time] > 7 THEN 'Over' 
     WHEN TAT = 14 AND  [Actual turn around time] > 14 THEN 'OVER'
     WHEN TAT = 28 AND  [Actual turn around time] > 28 THEN 'Over'
     WHEN TAT = 42 AND  [Actual turn around time] > 42 THEN 'Over'
     WHEN TAT = 52 AND  [Actual turn around time] > 52 THEN 'Over'
     WHEN TAT = 56 AND  [Actual turn around time] > 56 THEN 'Over'
     WHEN TAT = 62 AND  [Actual turn around time] > 62 THEN 'Over'
     WHEN TAT = 84 AND  [Actual turn around time] > 84 THEN 'Over'
     WHEN TAT = 112 AND  [Actual turn around time] > 112 THEN 'Over')
     ELSE 'TEST'
     END AS 'ITAT'
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not simplify the logic to this?

```
(CASE WHEN [Actual turn around time] > TAT THEN 'Over' 
      ELSE 'TEST'
 END) AS ITAT
```

You have a misplaced parentheses in your code.

If you want to limit the logic to just particular values of `TAT`, then extend the condition to:

```
(CASE WHEN [Actual turn around time] > TAT AND
           TAT IN (3, 7, 14, . . . )
      THEN 'Over' 
      ELSE 'TEST'
 END) AS ITAT
```

Comment: Thanks but I tried that as well it returns as a expression.

Comment: Would that be because [Actual turn around time] is a DATEDIFF

Comment: @Stack_user . . . I have no idea what our comments mean.  This answers the question that you asked, where `[Actual turn around time] ` looks like a column reference.